# How can I compile ES6 code to ES5 for the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-6, traceur

I have installed traceur using npm and have managed to compile a simple ES6 script. My problem is that the code that is generated is specific to node.js

I know that traceur can be run from the browser but I wanted to optimise further. Is There a way to run traceur from the command line (node) in similar way to how lesscss works?

Comment: I think the answer is probably here: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/CompilingOffline

Comment: Thank you very much. It appears than a --script option must be added. It's not too obvious from the command line help.

Comment: You could try using gulp or grunt: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-traceur https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-traceur

Comment: @tomwrong: answer your own question! Makes it easier to find, and you get *additional internet points*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I might be a bit late to the party, and you already found the solution as mentioned in your comment, but still I want to give an answer to make it easier for others to find the solution.*

It's possible to compile your ES6 code with adding `--script` to your command.

**Compile a single file**

```
$ traceur es6-code.js --script es5-code.js
```

**Compile multiple files to a single file**

```
$ traceur --out es6-code-1.js es6-code-2.js es6-code-3.js --script es5-code.min.js
```

Read more in [Compiling Offline](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Compiling-Offline) and [Options for Compiling](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Options-for-Compiling) in the Traceur wiki.